# render many svg images with datatatables in javascirpt

Tags: javascript, datatables, rdkit

My goal is to create a chemistry related website. I want to show a table with different data, also containing a svg-image per row. This image is made by the module "rdkit.js". The rendering works fine in a minimal example. But when i increase the amount of rows, or the complexity/size of the images, in the table the loading takes forever and i get the following error-message when i try to move the the next page of the table:

[Errormessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMedm.png)

The amount of svg images seem to big for rdkit.js and datatables.

Here is my code. This is only the relevant code (in my opinion):

```
function main(dataSet){ //dataset holds the data -> array of dict 
    window.initRDKitModule().then(function (RDKit) { //this is necessary for the rdkit to load
        console.log("RDKit version: " + RDKit.version());
        window.RDKit = RDKit;
        makeTable(dataSet);
        getDownload(dataSet); // for a downloadbutton
      })
      .catch(() => {
      });
}

function getSVG(smiles){
    var mol = RDKit.get_mol(smiles);
    var svg = mol.get_svg()
    return svg

}

function makeTable(dataSet){
    console.log(dataSet)
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        data : dataSet,
        deferRender: true,
        deferLoading: 25,
        columns: [
            {       
                className: 'dt-control', 
                orderable: false,
                data: null,
                defaultContent: '',
            },
        { 
            "render": function(data, type, JsonResultRow, meta) { //meta holds meta data like the row number, beginning with 0
            svg = getSVG("C1=NC2=C(N1COCCO)N=C(NC2=O)N")
            return '<div > '+svg+' </div>'
        }
        },
        {"data" : "formula"},
        {"data" : "MolWt"},
        {"data" : "logP"},
        {"data" : "tpsa"},
        {"data" : "NumHAcceptors"},
        {"data" : "NumHDonors"},
        {"data" : "RingCount"},

        ],
    });
        // Add event listener for opening and closing details
        $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.dt-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr'); //gets the row of the present datatable
        var row = table.row(tr);    //and saves it in the var row
        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        } else {
            // Open this row
            row.child(format(row.data())).show(); //if not shown yet show it
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    });
}
```

Is there a way to display all these images without running out of memory? Maybe rendering only those rows which are visible for the user?  I already tried to use the "deferRender: true" option in datatables, but without any change. Maybe i used it the wrong way. Later my datatable might contain several thousand rows which could become an even bigger problem.

I use Django as my backend.

Many Thanks in advance for your Help!!!!

Comment: This is an interesting post on the forums: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/51119/how-to-reduce-no-of-render-function-for-display-is-deferrender-not-working-properly-in-my-case I'm wondering if setting `orderable` to `false` on the SVG column might not help? Maybe adding a small demo on JSFiddle will help us get to the bottom of the issue. You can mimic AJAX calls there too.

Comment: Thanks mate! The solution shown there and the "orderable" on "false" worked for me! Maybe later i might have to use server side processing.

Comment: Good stuff - glad it helped! Please add your own answer to help people in similar situations :-)